# Stripe connect onboarding doesn't have country options?

Tags: stripe-payments

trying to integrate stripe connect in my site. But when I go to the stripe connect site and generate a sign up link for the account, it only shows the US as an option even though I have every country toggled in the dashboard?

```
const account = await stripe.accounts.create({
        type: 'express',
        business_type: 'individual',
        business_profile: { url: `https://dialect.so/@${username}` },
        email,
        capabilities: {
            transfers: { requested: true },
            card_payments: { requested: true }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the connected account to be able to select the country in Connect Onboarding, then do not set the capabilities on the account on creation.

```
const account = await stripe.accounts.create({
        type: 'express',
        business_type: 'individual',
        business_profile: { url: `https://dialect.so/@${username}` },
        email
    })
```

If the platform does not set capabilities on the account explicitly, Stripe sets capabilities on the account based on the country configuration set in https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/connect/express.

Answer (score 0):

Because the default [country](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create?lang=node#create_account-country) of a newly created account is the same as platform's, you shall specify the `country` when creating an account for your overseas user.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the flow that we want, it should be able to select country within the stripe flow right? connect.stripe.com should be able to handle countrys